# Using Frida on XCode Simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, frida

Does anyone has experience with setting up Frida to work with XCode Simulator? I have been searching online but this is the closest thing I've got (https://programmersought.com/article/54464074345/)
However, when I compile and run the app on simulator, I did not see what was described in "quick smoke test". Any help is very appreciated !

Comment: Please don't only reference external web pages. Always include the commands you have executed so we know exactly how far you got. Based on your description I assume you are on an Intel based Mac. Have you tested if you can see the simulator in libimobiledevice tools (install via brew). E.g. do you get the simulator info if you execute `ideviceinfo`?

Answer (score 2):

As iOS simulator is essentially running apps on your native mac OS host, you can interacts with apps directly as if they are running on your machine.

In a nutshell:

- Don't use `-U` argument as iOS simulator is not a USB device
- `frida-ps` should give you a list of running processes, including the apps running on the simulator.
- The rest of the APIs should work in the same way they do for mac OS host.